# How to determine if a customAttribute from a class is equals to another?

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

check that I have a customAttribute called `ResponseAttributes`. I have declared an interface and several concrete classes `{ Question 1, Question2, Question3 }`

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ResponseAttribute : Attribute { }
public interface IQuestion { }

public class Question1 : IQuestion
{
    [Response]
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public Question1() { Response = "2+1"; }
}

public class Question2 : IQuestion
{
    [Response]
    public decimal Response { get; set; }
    public Question2() { Response = 5; }
}

public class Question3 : IQuestion
{
    [Response]
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public Question3() { Response = "2+1"; }
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is how to verify a class which contains that attribute is equals to another?

I mean:

```
        List<IQuestion> questions = new List<IQuestion>()
        {
            new Question1(), new Question2()
        };

        Question3 question3 = new Question3();

        foreach (var question in questions)
        {
            // how to verify this condition:
            // if (customAttribute from question3 is equals to customAttribute fromquestion)
            // of course the question3 is equals to 1
        }
```

As you can, they are different types, that's the reason why I set as `ResponseAttribute`.

Comment: Why do you need an attribute at all? If your interface included a Response property (i.e. decimal Response { get;set;} ), you could compare your variables through the common property provided by the interface

Comment: The problem here, is every questions has a response property, but each one is different datatype, so I was thinking that is good to have the customAttribute

Comment: One of the benefits of using an interface IQuestion is that you can enforce the use of a standard comparable data type for some output. You may not want to change how Response works (keeping different datatypes) but you may consider adding an interface property `Answer` as a string that, upon implementation, outputs the Response as a string for comparison. Then your for-each becomes trivial, `if questionA.Answer == questionB.Answer...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using an interface, with Resposnse property (type object)
if you can not, you could use a class-level attribute that tell you the "Response property" than, you can use reflection on that property

Example:

```
public class ResponseAttribute : Attribute { 
  public string PropertyName { get; set }
}

[ResponseAttribute ("CustomResponse")}
public class Question1 {
   public string CustomResponse;
}

via reflection
foreach(var question in questions) {
   var responseAttr = (ResponseAttribute) question.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ResponseAttribute));

var questionResponse= question.GetType().GetProperty(responseAttr.PropertyName,question,null);
}
```

Comment: Please, can you explain more about the second option?

Answer (score 0):

try overriding equals method:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is IQuestion)
            return this.Response == ((IQuestion)obj).Response;
        else
            return base.Equals(obj);
    }
```

hope this helps